# get value from other react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react, and a little bit confused by how to get value from other components. I am building a Podomoro clocks app. these are consists of:
- setting of session time,
- setting of rest time,
- a clock for counting down.
how do I get value of session time and rest time, assigned to clock?

here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var TimerSetting = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
      return {
        time: 0
      };
    },
    afterUpdateTime: function(callback){
      this.afterUpdateTimeAction = callback;
    },
    increment: function(){
      var time = this.state.time + 1;
      time = Math.max(time, 0);
      this.setState({
        time: time
      });
      this.afterUpdateTimeAction(time);
    },
    decrement: function(){
      var time = this.state.time - 1;
      time = Math.max(time, 0);
      this.setState({
        time: time
      });
      this.afterUpdateTimeAction(time);
    },
    render: function(){
      return (
        <div className="timerSetting">
          <div className="titleSetting">
            {this.props.title}
          </div>
          <div className="minus" onClick={this.decrement}>
            -
          </div>
          <div className="time-setting">
            {this.state.time}
          </div>
          <div className="plus" onClick={this.increment}>
          +
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  });

  var PodomoroClock = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
      return {
        time: 0
      };
    },
    updateSession: function(time){
      this.setState({
        time: time
      });
    },
    render: function(){
      return(
        <div className="clock">
          {this.state.time}
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  var TimerWrapper= React.createClass({
    updateClockSession: function(com){
      com.afterUpdateTime(this.updateChildSession);
    },
    updateChildSession: function(time){
      this.ref.podomoro.updateSession(time);
    },
    render: function(){
      return (
        <div className="timeWrapper">
          <div className="timer">
            <TimerSetting title="Session Length" ref={this.updateClockSession} />
            <TimerSetting title="Break Length" ref="break"/>
          </div>
          <div className="podomoroClock">
            <PodomoroClock ref='podomoro'/>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  React.render(<TimerWrapper title="class2" />, $('#content')[0]);

});
```

please I need your help? get stuck with it. I'm trying to use callback, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<TimerSetting title="Session Length" onTimeChanged={this.updateClockSession} />
```

And then you need to call your handler inside the `afterUpdate` function of the TimerSetting:

```
afterUpdateTime: function(time){
      this.props.onTimeChanged && this.props.onTimeChanged(time)
}
```

Note that your `TimerWrapper.onTimeChanged` function will now receive the time (integer) as input.